# Jersey: Error occurred when processing a response created from an already mapped exception

Tags: jersey

I am trying to add a custom exception mapper, but am getting the following error:

```
Error occurred when processing a response created from an already mapped exception.
```

I am using Dropwizard, Jersey, and Kotlin.

Answer (score 6):

The issue is that there are multiple ExceptionMappers for the same exception registered with your application. To fix the issue, make sure that there is only one ExceptionMapper per Exception class.

Note that this does not prevent registering exception mappers for sub classes. For example, an application can register a catch-all mapper for Exception or RuntimeException.

### OK: ExceptionMappers for subclasses

```
class UnhandledExceptionMapper : ExceptionMapper<Exception> { ... }
```

And also register more specific mappers.

```
class InvalidSearchExceptionMapper : ExceptionMapper<InvalidSearchException> { ... }
```

### NOT OK: Multiple ExceptionMappers for the same class

```
class UnhandledExceptionMapper : ExceptionMapper<Exception> { ... }
```

This will cause the error described in the question.

```
class OtherUnhandledExceptionMapper : ExceptionMapper<Exception> { ... }
```

Comment: I noticed however that Jersey allow an exception mapper is registered as class and another registered as an object, however on the class registered exception mapper will be used.