# Upgrade Exception of Google App Engine From Java 7 to Java 8 using latest plugin

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jersey, guice

In Current version, we are using Googleappengine SDK version(1.9.25) and Java 7. In order we are using old google plugin for our project.

Now Java 7 is deprecate for GAE. so we started migrate the project to new plugin (SDK version - 1.9.64) and Java 8.

I Referring these website to convert maven application.

```
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/deprecations/java7
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/migrating-to-java8
https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/migrating
```

**web.xml:**

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <!-- Next three lines are for request dispatcher actions -->
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Rest_api</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.back2family.app.config.JerseyConfiguration</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Rest_api</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/app/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-endpoints</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.64</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-appengine</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.64</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.endpoints</groupId>
            <artifactId>endpoints-framework</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-datastore</artifactId>
            <version>1.35.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.objectify/objectify -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.objectify</groupId>
            <artifactId>objectify</artifactId>
            <version>5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            <artifactId>hk2-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0-b61</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.inject/guice -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.inject.extensions/guice-servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.hk2/guice-bridge -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice-bridge</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0-b61</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180130</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.floreysoft/jmte -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.floreysoft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmte</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sendgrid/sendgrid-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sendgrid</groupId>
            <artifactId>sendgrid-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.libphonenumber/libphonenumber -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.libphonenumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>libphonenumber</artifactId>
            <version>8.9.9</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Getting Exception like

**Console Log:**

```
Jul 02, 2018 10:16:36 AM org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder process
SEVERE: Error occurred when processing a response created from an already mapped exception.
Jul 02, 2018 10:16:36 AM org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor aroundWriteTo
SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class com.back2family.app.rest.StandardResponse, genericType=class com.back2family.app.rest.StandardResponse.
Jul 02, 2018 10:16:36 AM org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder process
SEVERE: Error occurred when processing a response created from an already mapped exception.
2018-07-02 10:16:36.738:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:qtp1020923989-49: 
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:432)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1772)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.AsyncCacheFilter.doFilter(AsyncCacheFilter.java:58)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:48)
```

Comment: Try to change to the Jackson package, shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26207252/messagebodywriter-not-found-for-media-type-application-json#answer-29137657).
It seems there are multiple ExceptionMappers for the same exception registered. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49683752/jersey-error-occurred-when-processing-a-response-created-from-an-already-mapped).
Did you check the error log on Cloud Console? What do they say? Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31289470/http-500-internal-server-error-in-simple-rest-based-program-confused-in-get-and)

Comment: Yes, I added this Maven
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
 <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
 <version>2.9.6</version>
</dependency>

Comment: and delete my Maven repo folder, regenerate the maven's to solve this issue

Comment: Thanks Diogo A for your response.